# SQL to .csv - How to Get Rid of Double Array Entries

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm using php code to get the values from a database table with 3 columns and put them into a .csv file

The problem is that I'm always getting double entries of every column.  Here is the first row that shows the problem.  The array should be 3 items but it is 6.

```
array(6) { [0]=> string(2) "99" ["id"]=> string(2) "99" [1]=> int(9) ["survey_id"]=> int(9) [2]=> string(10) "Very Small" ["item"]=> string(10) "Very Small" }
```

Here is how I'm getting the above data

```
  $sql="Select * from Percept_Segments";
  $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
  while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)){
    var_dump($row);
    exit();

  }
```

I've tried using array_values but this gives the same result.
Is there a way to just get the 3 entries like in the original database table?

Comment: Yes.  But often some entries should be the same as others so this would result in an additional problem.

Comment: Can you set the fetchType of `sqlsrv_fetch_array` to `SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC`. According to the doc (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php) it returns both assoc and numeric as default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the fetchType of `sqlsrv_fetch_array` like this:

`sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)`

By default according to the [Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php) it sets the return array with both associative and numeric.